# How do I set up an IOS application for development with a team (react native)

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native

I'm working on a react-native application and I would like for it to work on IOS.  In IOS, I'm learning that there are all these configurations such as bundle identifier, team, app signing etc, and I'm just wondering if anyone has any articles they would recommend that explains all or parts of this?  I'm new to IOS development but am looking to learn.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This article is good for knowing what to do when publishing an. app :

https://reactnative.dev/docs/publishing-to-app-store

For xcode related configurations you can check

https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup

Hope it helps feel free for doubts

Answer (score 0):

- https://medium.com/swlh/creating-an-application-with-react-native-f31f9a6f2859
- https://levelup.gitconnected.com/react-native-how-to-setup-your-first-app-a36c450a8a2f
- https://medium.com/react-native-development/deploying-a-react-native-app-for-ios-pt-1-a79dfd15acb8

I think these will be helpful!